# Using Cronjob for changing data window (on MAC)

Tags: python, sql, cron, jupyter-notebook, vertica

I have a python code (on Jupiter Notebook) which runs several SQL queries and updates existing table in Vertica by inserting data of the given week.
Say, every Monday I run the data of the last week, and every time I put it manually, for example:

```
first_date = "'2019-04-15'"
last_date =  "'2019-04-21'"
```

Is there any way it can be done automatically? As I understand,I can use cron to have the file running with given frequency, but it will run the same window date every time... Do you have any ideas of how it could be done? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always run it on a Monday, then you can use below script:

```
import pandas as pd
startdate = (pd.to_datetime('today') + pd.DateOffset(days=-7)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
enddate = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print('from: ', startdate, ' to: ', enddate)
```

Result:

```
from:  2019-04-15  to:  2019-04-22
```

BUT if you missed your monday schedule and it is already thursday, then you can still get the last week's monday with the script below:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
startdate = today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday(), weeks=1)
enddate = today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday())
print('from: ', startdate, ' to: ', enddate)
```

Result:

```
from:  2019-04-15  to:  2019-04-22
```